# Running average of employee salary

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is it possible to update the running average salary while inserting it into the table?

```
NAME  SAL   AVGSAL
ABC   10    10
ABD   20    15
ABF   60    30
```

In the above table while I insert NAME and SAL, the average salary should be calculated automatically including the current row, is it possible in single SQL ?  ABC  AVGSAL = 10/1 = 10  for ABD  AVGSAL = (10+20)/2 = 15 for ABF AVGSAL = (60+20+10)/3 = 30.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you insert the data in the table you cannot use it to calculate the average. The only way to achieve is first insert the rows and then write another statement to update

Comment: @roshaga why not?

Comment: Relational database do not allow u to query data before it is inserted in the table. For running average the requirement is to refer to the current row data which is still not inserted in the table. So it will not be possible. You will have to manually specify that value someway. Which i feel will be a bit more work then writing 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?  You need to specify the value twice though:

```
insert into table1 select ?, (sum(t2.sal) + ?) / (count(*) + 1) from table1 t2;
```

For a normal insert you can refer to previous column.  Sub-queries on the same table is not allowed.